# Openvpn3 client failed calling D-Bus method Connect on Debian buster

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, dbus

I had a healthy **Openvpn3** client running on my laptop, and every day used to successfully connect to my company's vpn without any hurdle.

However today things went wrong, and I'm no longer able to connect. This is the message error:

> session-start: ** ERROR ** Failed to start new session: Failed calling
> D-Bus method Connect: Timeout was reached

I know yesterday **openvpn3** was updated from repos.

Googling, I haven't found any interesting, just the usual `purge openvpn3 and install` again, which obviously I've done, and again there is no change. I can't connect to a remote vpn which is essential in my work.

Other possible source of error is the `.ovpn` config file, which I downloaded again today, so this not the cause.

I have the not so weird idea that either **openvpn3** is bugged or there is a conflict with **python3**. A team mate had the same problem 1 week ago in a Windows machine. He reinstalled the GUI client and solved the issue.

This is my machine's OS, apt updated everyday.

```
Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

kernel  Linux 4.19.0-17-amd64
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens that latest releases of **openvpn3** are tricky,  and the best solution was to downgrade version.  Nothing more to do,  and wait till a non buggy release is deployed.

As I stated in my question,  a teammate, Windows user had the same issue.

So, the problem is code being released without proper testing,  hence,  do not ever trust latest updates from **openvpn**!

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 using `openvpn3/focal 14~beta+focal`. Downgraded to `13~beta-1+focal`, and the client is working fine again. Thanks!

Comment: how to downgrade?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @digitai answer for those looking to for the downgrade command you can run this. Tested on ubuntu 20.04.

> **Pre-requisite: your updated openvpn3 client application must not be uninstalled.**

```
sudo apt install openvpn3=13~beta-1+focal
```